# Filtering with an all function with two dropdown lists

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to create a filter with two dropdown lists with All options for both lists. Currently I can figure out how to get two dropdown lists to work, and how to make an all function with one dropdown list, but not with two lists.

The link to the sheet is here

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dfj60oEmm5w6W9ZoRQ2dpXqFMs1IOrtXulXi0qoG6kA/edit?usp=sharing

The code without the "All" function is below

=sort(FILTER('List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!A:P,IF(B1,('List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!$B:$B=B1),)+IF(C1,('List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!$C:$C=1),)+IF(D1,('List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!$D:$D=D1),)+IF(E1,('List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!$E:$E=E1),)+IF(F1,('List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!$F:$F=F1),)+IF(G1,('List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!$G:$G=G1),),'List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!P:P=I1,'List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!M:M=K1),1,TRUE)

Comment: You've asked for help, but you haven't given us anything to work with: no spreadsheet link, no image, no data simulation, no ranges. You mention that you tried X and Y formulas that partially worked, but you haven't shared those. In short, you haven't provided enough for anyone to help you. Consider sharing a link to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it) with the link permissions set, at the time you create the link, to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." That way, the volunteer contributors here can see the problem, test solutions and leave any working solutions for you.

Comment: My apologies, I haven't used this site before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with your formula modified as follows:

`=ArrayFormula(SORT(FILTER('List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!A:P,IF(B1,('List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!$B:$B=B1),)+IF(C1,('List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!$C:$C=1),)+IF(D1,('List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!$D:$D=D1),)+IF(E1,('List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!$E:$E=E1),)+IF(F1,('List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!$F:$F=F1),)+IF(G1,('List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!$G:$G=G1),),IF((I1="")+(I1="All"),ROW('List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!A:A),'List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!P:P=I1),IF((K1="")+(K1="All"),ROW('List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!A:A),'List of Classes, Divided by Classes'!M:M=K1)),1,TRUE))`

I wrote it such that either "All" or a blank cell in I1 or K1 will result in all matches according to checked days.

The IF clauses in both cases simply say that if the value of I1 or K1, respectively, is "All" or blank, to return all row numbers as the Boolean value. Since any number other than 0 is TRUE, you get the effect of "everything" for that IF check.